# How to add the aspx.cs code to get the selected value of radio button as per the aspx page as shown in the screenshot below?

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, asp.net, aspx, .net

[image]

This is the code for retrieving the Question and options dynamically from SharePoint list. How to get the value of selected radio buttons and store it to a variable using the C# or SP code. Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: first check if RadioButton1.Checked is true and then use RadioButton1.Text to get its value...same for other 3 radio buttons. Refer this for more https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8

Comment: RadioButton1.Checked is not itentified by the intellisence and getting an error. Can you please tell me where is the mistake.

Comment: test once writing directly in control  <asp:RadioButton id="Radio1" Text="Typical" Checked="True" GroupName="RadioGroup1" runat="server" />

Comment: Yes have added the line directly. Even after this Radio1 is not recognized by intellisense. Is it because of the repeater and it's ID? Because I'm able to fetch the ID of the repeater. But unable to proceed with this ID.

Comment: I don't think Repeater causing any issue...I have tested with it its working...Could you please paste code instead img so I can test it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)(repeater.FindControl("RadioButton1"));
```

Comment: Thankyou. It is working with this:
var rb1=item.FindControl("RadioButton1") as RadioButton;

Comment: Glad it helped 